# In iOS tweak development, I cannot overwrite/write file with :writeToFile:atomically method

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, jailbreak, theos

First of all, I am new to iOS tweak development and sorry if I asked something really seems like dumb. However, I cannot figure out what is the actual problem yet.

### In the following code, I want to do:

- Edit the 'integer' value in the dictionary.

### So what I did (Expected):

1. Read the application's 'plist' file in the data container. (/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application//Library/Preferences/...plist)
2. Edit the specific integer value from plist by resetting(removing and setting the value again) because the value is immutable.
3. Save to the file with the `writeToFile` method.

### Environment:

- THEOS with WSL1.0 (Windows Pro 1909)
- iPhone 10,4 with iOS 13.5 (Unc0ver)

Also, the following code is in the preference bundle template.

### CODE:

```c
        // NOTE: Show alert<loading>(applying);
        UIAlertController *alertLoading = [UIAlertController
            alertControllerWithTitle:@"Applying settings"
            message:@"The settings are being applied..."
            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert
        ];
        [self presentViewController:alertLoading animated:YES completion:nil];

        // NOTE: Get application UUID and data container path.
        FBApplicationInfo *applicationProxy = [LSApplicationProxy applicationProxyForIdentifier:applicationBundleIdentifier];
        NSString *applicationDataContainerPath = applicationProxy.dataContainerURL.path;
        NSString *applicationPreferencePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Preference/%@.plist", applicationDataContainerPath, tweakBundleIdentifier];

        // NOTE: Read preference file into memory and find the object.
        NSMutableDictionary *applicationPreference = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:applicationPreferencePath];
        NSMutableDictionary *applicationPreferenceAdUnitSetting = [applicationPreference[@"AdFitStore"][@"AdUnitSetting"] objectAtIndex:0];

        int KakaotalkAdfitUnitPreferenceMaxReqCount = 0;

        // NOTE: Check if the extension is enabled;
        if ([isEnabled isEqual:@0]) {
            // NOTE: Disabled;
            KakaotalkAdfitUnitPreferenceMaxReqCount = 20;
        }

        // NOTE: Update the value.
        [applicationPreferenceAdUnitSetting removeObjectForKey:@"fcMaxCount"];
        [applicationPreferenceAdUnitSetting setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:KakaotalkAdfitUnitPreferenceMaxReqCount] forKey:@"fcMaxCount"];

        // NOTE: Write preference file into original path.
        [applicationPreference writeToFile:@applicationPreferencePath atomically:YES];

        // NOTE: Hide alert<loading>(applied);
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

### Original PLIST file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AdFitStore</key>
    <dict>
        <key>userAgent</key>
        <string>Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148</string>
        <key>AdFitSDKVersion</key>
        <string>3.3.4</string>
        <key>AdFitSAL</key>
        <dict>
            ...
        </dict>
        <key>AdUnitSetting</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DAN-1hux82hxke720</key>
            <dict>
                <key>reqInterval</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>fcMaxCount</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>lastViewabledDate</key>
                <date>2020-07-09T12:25:30Z</date>
                <key>nextResetDate</key>
                <date>2020-07-09T15:00:00Z</date>
                <key>lastRequestedDate</key>
                <date>2020-07-11T17:14:51Z</date>
                <key>fcInterval</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>viewableCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - change

```
 [applicationPreference writeToFile:@applicationPreferencePath atomically:YES];
```

to

```
 [applicationPreference writeToFile:applicationPreferencePath atomically:YES];
```

ie drop the `@`.